# Pausing sawtooth generator given an input

Tags: voltage-regulator, analog, 555

I created the following sawtooth generator to go between 5v and 10v. I need a way to keep the output at 5v given a while a certain input signal is high. I've tried various combinations of MOSFETs and diodes to no avail, so I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Edit: The input signal will be a 15v signal that is high for a few milliseconds. During this time the sawtooth should jump down to 5v from where it is and then continue ramping up to 10v when the input signal goes low.

Comment: Just turn off the current source, synchronized to the discharge line going active, I'd imagine. Why have you only described your control line no better than when, "a certain input signal is high?" Provide ***detailed*** information about your signalling and specify detailed instructions about how it is to be applied in controlling the rest of this circuit.

Comment: I apologize for being so vague. The input signal will be a 15v signal that is high for a few milliseconds. During this time the sawtooth should jump down to 5v from where it is and then continue ramping up to 10v when the input signal goes low.

Comment: What does the reset pin do for you?

Comment: @anonamoose definitely **edit** your question to include what you wrote in your comment. It's crucial and should be in there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need a way to keep the output at 5v given a while a certain input
>   signal is high

Use an analogue switch to connect 5 volts to the 0.01 uF capacitor. Use an analogue switch that can run from 15 volts and make sure it has a lowish on resistance so that the 5 volts is not affected by the current source.

Alternatively, use a MOSFET and a resistor across the 0.01 uF capacitor. The MOSFET should be N channel and have the source grounded. The resistor value should be 100 kohm so that 50uA*R = 5 volts.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The issue was I was not using the 100k resistor when I was connecting a MOSFET there. I decided to use a voltage controlled switch,however, because it has a quicker drop to the 5v.